# Nested empty class

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
class nest_empty
{
   class empty{};
};
```

Will the size of `nest_empty` be 1 (on my implementation sizof an empty class is 1)? If yes why? Can `nest_empty` be considered as an empty class?

**EDIT:**

```
class nest_empty
{
   class empty{};
   empty d;
};
```

Will the size of `nest_empty` still be 1? If yes why?

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I'm pretty sure that nested classes are 'static'-like much like regular classes.  So your nest_empty class would still be size 1 unless you gave it an instance of empty();  I'm curious to see what the answer is.

Comment: @equilibrium: changing the question after having answers without properly identifying what has been changed is very confusing... I've added a **EDIT** separator.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your first version of `nest_empty` is an empty class (no non-static data members, and no non-empty bases), so if they have size 1 in your implementation, it has size 1.

"Why" is because empty classes have size 1 on your implementation, which in turn is because they can't have size 0 (the standard forbids it), and your implementer has chosen 1.

Your second `nest_empty` is not an empty class (it has a non-static data member). It could legally have size 1, since its only non-static data member, `d`, is of type `empty`, which is an empty class and hence presumably of size 1.

I can't tell you whether it actually will have size 1 on your implementation, though. Ask your compiler.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. `empty` is just in the namespace of `nest_empty`.

To be clearer, the line `class nest_empty{};` simply defines `nest_empty`. It does not declare any member in `empty`.

Comment: The size will be non 0 value based on what the implementation feels is right. period.

Comment: in that case, the second `nest_empty` is not an empty class (it has a member - even if the member has a type which is an empty class). And yes the size of `nest_empty` will still be the size of its contents plus padding, which is the size of `empty` plus padding, which will be, as pointed out by the other posters, some positive value.

Answer (score 3):

It's not mandatory for `sizeof(nest_empty)` to be 1, but it won't be zero.

$9.3 says: `Complete objects and member subobjects of class type shall have nonzero size.`

This is needed because if you create an array of `nest_empty`, each one has to have a different address from the other.

**EDIT**

Most probably, `sizeof(nest_empty)` will yield the same result in both version, but that it's not mandated. The only thing the standard says is that empty class will have nonzero size.

Comment: @equilibrium: the implementation is allowed (by the standard) to have `sizeof(nest_empty) == sizeof(empty)`. On most compilers, you'll get both equal to `1`.